# firebase auth keeps throwing an PLatformException on Vscode even I handle exceptions with try - catch

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm going through a weird behavior using the  `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method of firebase_auth

the `try catch` block should catch if an error is thrown but a `PLatformException` flows up in the editor like I did call a normal async/await method without catching errors :

the weird thing is that I already used the same code in a previous project and it's working fine, I did the same configuration, and it's working fine with correct auth data, just if there is an error it doesn't catch it
my code :

```
  Future handleLoginProcess(BuildContext context) async {

_handleInputsCases();
_startLoading();
try {
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: "barry.allen@example.com", password: "SuperSecretPassword!");
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  print('Failed with error code: ${e.code}');
  print(e.message);
}
_endLoading();
```

}

the thrown error seem to direct me to this:

```
if (errorCode is String && (errorMessage == null || errorMessage is String) && !buffer.hasRemaining) {
  throw PlatformException(code: errorCode, message: errorMessage as String?, details: errorDetails, stacktrace: errorStacktrace);
} else {
  throw const FormatException('Invalid envelope');
}
```

I'm missing something, what are the possible reasons to this, is it something related to vscode?

please share your ideas with me, thanks

Comment: What is error log

Comment: Did you solve this? I am currently encountering this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this code working well in your another project. then you should check SDK Version of both projects. You can find SDK version in YAML file.

Answer (score 1):

Check your flutter implementation too.

In pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_auth: ^3.11.2
```

Code

```
    Future loginWithUserEmail({@required String email, @required String password}) async{
    try{
      var userCredential = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password
      );
      //await _populateCurrentUser(userCredential.user);
      return userCredential.user != null;
    }catch(error){
      return error.toString();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When i went through this error the only solution i found was to create a whole new project on Firebase, on Google console and on my computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).